# WPF DataGrid Input key binding stops working after a while?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, key-bindings

Hi I have two input key bindings on a WPF DataGrid, which will evoke coresponding command when key is pressed, like the following:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="False" Focusable="True"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              EnableColumnVirtualization="False" EnableRowVirtualization="False" SelectionMode="Single"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=QueryClauses}" 
              SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedQueryClauseIndex}">
        <DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Insert" Command="{Binding DataContext.InsertQueryClause, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
            <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteQueryClause, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
        </DataGrid.InputBindings>
        ...
</DataGrid>
```

It works perfectly in the beginning, but after a while of editing/deleting on the editable DataGrid, the “Insert/Delete” command stops working, I debugged in the command, and the command was never fired, which means the DataGrid has somehow lost tracking of the keyboard input bindings.

I searched and find someone met a similar issue:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0cdabbe0-b96f-43a2-bcb0-842d1766c2c7/why-does-my-inputbinding-stop-working?forum=wpf

The post explains that the control has lost the binding because somehow it sees the e.handled = true, so that the inputs were bypassed.

However, this post didn't tell how to fix it, so anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked other post, seems set the following property solves the issue:

```
Focusable="True"
```

Thanks.